# Как мне посмотреть список всех all-server триггеров?

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

У меня есть logon-триггер (all server). Существует ли функция или процедура, которая возвращает список всех триггеров на сервере?

`select * from sys.triggers` возвращает пустую выборку (других триггеров, кроме упомянутого, нет).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для получения информации о триггерах уровня сервера обратитесь к системному представлению *sys.server_triggers*:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.server_triggers;
```

([документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-triggers-transact-sql)).

Представление *sys.triggers* возвращает информацию о DML- и DDL-триггерах в базе данных. Если запрос `select * from sys.triggers` возвращает пустую выборку, то либо в базе данных (в контексте которой он выполняется) нет триггеров, либо они есть, но у пользователя, выполняющего запрос, нет к ним доступа.